# Xcode undefined symbols ~ destructor

Tags: c++, xcode

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Matrix::~Matrix()", referenced from:
      _main in p1.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I get this error when trying to compile in xcode. The issue is with this destructor declaration in the header file. If I comment the destructor out, it builds successfully.

```
class Matrix {
public:
    ~Matrix();     
};
```

Comment: Where do you define the destructor?

Comment: I have three files: main, Matrix.hpp, and Matrix.cpp. The destructor is declared in Matrix.hpp and will be defined in Matrix.cpp.

Comment: What is it defined as in Matrix.cpp? And is it truly being compiled/linked in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined the destructor. When you comment it out, the destructor will be an implicitly declared destructor, and hence the linker finds it. You state "... will be defined". Does this imply you have not yet defined it?

From cppreference.com (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor)

> If no user-declared destructor is provided for a class type (struct,
>   class, or union), the compiler will always declare a destructor as an
>   inline public member of its class.